# The content of element type must match element - XML and DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I am new to XML and I try to make a DTD file but I get this error and I don't find the mistake.

`"The content of element type "persoane" must match "(persoana)"`

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE persoane SYSTEM "persoane.dtd">
<persoane>
    <persoana id="1">
        <nume>Popescu</nume>
        <prenume>Ion</prenume>
        <varsta>23</varsta>
        <adresa>
            <strada>Ioan Ciurea</strada>
            <numar>2</numar>
            <localitate>Falticeni</localitate>
            <judet>Suceava</judet>
            <tara>Romania</tara>
        </adresa>
        
    </persoana>
    <persoana id="2">
        <nume>Popescu</nume>
        <prenume>Vasile</prenume>
        <varsta>26</varsta>
        <adresa>
            <strada>Ioan Ciurea 2</strada>
            <numar>2</numar>
            <localitate>Suceava</localitate>
            <judet>Suceava</judet>
            <tara>Romania</tara>
        </adresa>
        <experienta>
            <domeniu>Tech</domeniu>
            <ani>2</ani>
            <limbaj>C#</limbaj>
        </experienta>
    </persoana>
</persoane>
```

DTD Code

```
<!ELEMENT persoane (persoana)>
<!ELEMENT persoana (nume, prenume, varsta, adresa, experienta?)>
<!ATTLIST persoana id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT nume (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prenume (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT varsta (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT adresa (strada, numar, localitate, judet, tara)>
<!ELEMENT strada (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT numar (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT localitate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT judet (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT tara (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT experienta (domeniu, ani, limbaj)>
<!ELEMENT domeniu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ani (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT limbaj (#PCDATA)>
```

I tried to look after the order of elements but the order seems good to me. Can someone give a me a hint or something?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error with `xmlstarlet`, but everything seems to be valid.

Comment: I found the solution. I forgot the ```+``` in ```<!ELEMENT persoane (persoana)>``` . Changed to ```<!ELEMENT persoane (persoana+)>``` and now it is working

Comment: Glad you found a solution on your own. Congrats.